# Integrate existing application interface with Kafka

Tags: java, json, rest, apache-kafka

I would like to integrate an existing application with Kafka.

The application is not under my control so I am not able to change the way it communicates. Application sends JSON request to REST API backend.

How can I put Kafka between application and its backend without changing the code?

Comment: JSON request is a http request where as Kafka uses it's own protocol to communicate. So you need someone in between to translate, I think it's way too much work. Simplest way is to edit the code in the existing app.

Answer (score 1):

Simply inserting Kafka between 2 existing applications is not necessarily a good idea especially if they won't be taking advantage of it, like scale for example. As you didn't describe your use case, I can't tell.

That said if it's what you want to do, you can use Kafka Connect to integrate existing applications with Kafka. You should be able to build:

- a Source connector: to receive JSON requests from the app and insert them as records into Kafka
- a Sink connector: to extract records from Kafka and send them to the backend

See the Connect docs: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect